# Adding to list (from class instance) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined a class in python containing a variety of restaurants and details on them. My task is now to create a list variable based on that class instance, allowing the user to add or print the list. The problem I'm facing is in the (ans == 2) statement where the user can add their new restaurants and details of them.

This is the code

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self,name,website,cuisine):
        self.name = name
        self.website = website
        self.cuisine = cuisine

dominoes = Restaurant("Dominoes", "www.dominoes.co.uk", "pizza")
yosushi = Restaurant("Yo Sushi!", "www.yosushi.co.uk", "sushi")
fiveguys = Restaurant("Five Guys", "www.fiveguys.co.uk" ,"burger")
```

The part I'm doing is this next one and have been told that the above class has already been defined.

```
def menu():
    restaurants = [dominoes, yosushi, fiveguys]
    ans= int(input("CS1822 Restaurant DB\n1. Display restaurant list\n2. Add a restaurant\n3. 
Exit\nPlease enter your choice:"))

while (ans != 3):

    if (ans == 1):
        for i in restaurants:
            print(i.name,i.website,i.cuisine)
        menu()

    if (ans == 2):
        new_res = (input("Enter restaurant name: "))
        restaurants.append(new_res)
        new_res.website = input("Enter website: ")
        new_res.cuisine = input("Enter cuisine: ")
        menu()

    if (ans == 3):
        print("Goodbye!")
```

This is the error I recieve

```
***Error***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__tester__.python3", line 22, in <module>
    while (ans != 3):
NameError: name 'ans' is not defined
```

My two problems I would please like help for are:
a) my while loop says that variable ans is undefined and is not
b) my if (ans == 2) statement is completely wrong and is not running at all, stating that new_res is not an object that can be appended.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation as it is makes the while loop NOT a part of the menu() function. The reason why it says it's undefined is because the while loop doesn't have access to ans because it only exists within the menu() function.

```
def menu():
    restaurants = [dominoes, yosushi, fiveguys]
    ans= int(input("CS1822 Restaurant DB\n1. Display restaurant list\n2. Add 
          a restaurant\n3. Exit\nPlease enter your choice:"))

    while (ans != 3):

        if (ans == 1):
            for i in restaurants:
                print(i.name,i.website,i.cuisine)
            menu()

        if (ans == 2):
            new_res = (input("Enter restaurant name: "))
            restaurants.append(new_res)
            new_res.website = input("Enter website: ")
            new_res.cuisine = input("Enter cuisine: ")
            menu()

        if (ans == 3):
            print("Goodbye!")
```

These 3 following lines are the issue with ans == 2. You're treating the string variable 'new_res' as a Restaurant object.

```
restaurants.append(new_res)
new_res.website = input("Enter website: ")
new_res.cuisine = input("Enter cuisine: ")
```

You need to create a new Restaurant object and then append the restaurant list.

```
if (ans == 2):
    res_name = input("Enter restaurant name: ")
    res_website = input("Enter website: ")
    res_cuisine = input("Enter cuisine: ")
    new_res = Restaraunt(res_name, res_website, res_cuisine)
    restaurants.append(new_res)
    menu()
```